# Where does a function receive its input when passing the function as an argument?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function forEach(array, action) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    action(array[i]);
}
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;
forEach(numbers, function(number) {
  sum += number; 
});
console.log(sum);
```

Where does the function(number){ sum += number; } receive its arguments when passed? Does the resulting function look like this?

```
function(array[i]){sum += array[i]}
```

Comment: You'd be better off using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here. `let sum = numbers.reduce((x,y) => x+y);`

Answer (score 2):

The normal way: Between the parenthesis when it gets called.

```
action(array[i]);
       ^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

> Where does the function(number){ sum += number; } receive its arguments when passed?

You have created a function expression and passed it as an argument to the function (*forEach*). That function has one argument. It could be used while calling it.

```
action(array[i]);
//array[i] will be received as an argument to the passed function expression
```

Inside `forEach` function `action` would be a function reference. And that function reference is capable of passing one known parameter. So you can call it in anyways you want.